# Change nested list of symbols to nested list of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, symbols

I have some nested lists of symbols, all of the same format, and I wish to convert them to nested lists of integers, i.e.

```
{e1,{e1,{e1,e2}}} -> {1,{1,{1,2}}}
```

Any quick ways to do this?

Note: I will always have nested lists of that form, but their length may vary and the symbols may not always have single digit integers in them, e.g.

```
{e4,{e200,{e1,{e11,e23}}}} -> {4,{200,{1,{11,23}}}}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
symbols = {e4, {e200, {e1, {e11, e23}}}};
Map[FromDigits@StringDrop[SymbolName[#], 1] &, symbols, {-1}]
```

> {4, {200, {1, {11, 23}}}}

```
Map[FromDigits @ StringCases[SymbolName[#], NumberString] &, symbols, {-1}]
```

> {4, {200, {1, {11, 23}}}}

Alternative versions, as suggested by Kuba,

```
Function[, FromDigits@StringDrop[SymbolName[#], 1], Listable]@symbols
Function[, FromDigits@StringCases[SymbolName[#], NumberString], Listable]@symbols
```

And, inspired by Jack LaVigne's comment, `Replace` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
Replace[symbols, s_Symbol:>   FromDigits[StringDrop[SymbolName[s], 1]],∞ ]
symbols /. Except[List, s_Symbol] :> FromDigits@StringDrop[SymbolName[s], 1]
```

Finally, per J.M.'s comment, a variation on Coolwater's answer with combination of `ToExpression` and `StringDelete`:

```
 ToExpression @ StringDelete[LetterCharacter]@ToString@symbols
```

Comment: Here's an alternative for `Map`: `Function[sym, ..., Listable]`.

Comment: Thank you @Kuba; great suggestion.

Comment: @kglr Another alternative for `Map` is to use `ReplaceAll`. `symbols /. 
 e_Symbol /; Not[MatchQ[e, List]] :> 
  FromDigits@StringDrop[SymbolName[e], 1]`

Comment: Thank you@JackLaVigne; I added the alternatives with `ReplaceAll` and `Replace`.

Comment: @JackLaVigne fyi `... /. e:Except[List, _Symbol] ...`

Comment: @Kuba Very nice. Thank you

Comment: Just a quick question, in the very first one of these solutions here `Map[FromDigits@StringDrop[SymbolName[#], 1] &, symbols, {-1}]`, what is the need for `FromDigits`?

Comment: Whilst I realise that speed with these functions is really not an issue, from what I have seen, removing the (possibly) unnecessary `FromDigits` makes  `Map[StringDrop[SymbolName[#], 1] &, symbols, {-1}]` by far the fastest option.

Comment: @DanielWilson-Nunn,  without `FromDigits` or `ToExpression` wrapping we  get `{"4", {"200", {"1", {"11", "23"}}}}` .

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively:

```
symbols = {e4, {e200, {e1, {e11, e23}}}};
ToExpression[StringReplace[ToString[symbols], "e" -> ""]]
```

> {4, {200, {1, {11, 23}}}}

Comment: ...or, `ToExpression[StringDelete[ToString[symbols], "e"]]`

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [SymbolToSubscript](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SymbolToSubscript/):

```
symbols = {e4, {e200, {e1, {e11, e23}}}};

ResourceFunction["SymbolToSubscript"][symbols] /. Subscript[a_, b_] :> b

(*{4, {200, {1, {11, 23}}}}*)
```